# Fill a Word 2010 form drop-down without using code?

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, word-2010

I have been tasked with updating a Word 2010 fillable form for one of our departments.  In various places in the form it uses a drop-down box with the same 20-or-so items in the list.  I would like to make it so all occurrences of this box fill from a master list, thus making it easier to update in the future.  I know in Excel you can do this with Data Validation and selecting a source list from somewhere else in the workbook.  Is it possible to do something similar (reference a table, hidden text, etc) in Word?  I have not been able to locate a feature in Word that looks promising, nor have my Google searches yielded anything useful.  I realize this would probably work in VBA, but I'm hoping to avoid adding code to the workbook if possible.  I would also prefer that the list be updateable by someone who does not know VBA.  I'm not looking to do the impossible, so if you know for a fact that this cannot be done, say so and I'll move on.
Thanks.